# How to Filter <li> based on drop down values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, filter

**I need to  filter the list item which is less than 5 by selecting a option from the drop down**

*Html Part*

```
<div data-role="content">
 <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
     <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="5" >less than 5</option>
    <option value="10" >less than 10</option>
</select>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">    
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-filtertext="4" class="de"><a href=#>Audi</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="3" class="de"><a href=#>BMW</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="2" class="it"><a href=#>Ferrari</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="7" class="it"><a href=#>Lamborghini</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="9" class="it"><a href=#>Maserati</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script part

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
var value = $('#select-choice-1').val();
$("ul").find("li").hide()
$("ul").find("li[data-filtertext<"+value+"]").show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8zkh3nj6/)**

You can do this too

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
$("ul").find("li").hide()
    $.each($("ul").find("li"),function(){
    //iterate through each li and check its filtertext value is < value
        if($(this).data('filtertext')<value)
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works.. Thanks @guruprasad

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for filtering jQuery object based on condition

```js
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  $("ul li").hide().filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).data('filtertext'),10) < val;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content">
  <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="5">less than 5</option>
    <option value="10">less than 10</option>
  </select>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li data-filtertext="4" class="de"><a href=#>Audi</a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="3" class="de"><a href=#>BMW</a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="2" class="it"><a href=#>Ferrari</a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="7" class="it"><a href=#>Lamborghini</a>
      </li>
      <li data-filtertext="9" class="it"><a href=#>Maserati</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('li').hide().filter(function() {
        return parseInt($(this).data('filtertext'), 10) < parseInt(value, 10);
    }).show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zLLff3n/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select-choice-1').change(function(){
 var value = $('#select-choice-1').val();
 $("ul li").hide();
 $("ul li").each(function(){
   data = $(this).attr('data-filtertext');
   if(typeof data == 'undefined' || data == ''){
      $("ul li").show();
   }else if(data < value){
    $(this).show();
   }
 });    
}
```